# Java Xbootclasspath , relative path

Tags: java, bootclasspath

I need to change Java Xbootclasspath property when using alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar . If I add absolute path to the Xbootclasspath, with

```
/Users/MYLINUXNAME/projectname/thisrdparty/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar
```

then it works. But I need to set it as relative path, so that everybody in a project will be able to run it. How do I do it? I tried playing with

```
-Xbootclasspath/p:${user.dir}/projectname/thisrdparty/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar
```

But no luck. 
So does anybody know how to put relative path into the bootclasspath ?
Any ideas?
Thanks!